# Provide third order Taylor expansion of stable manifold near a saddle point in a dynamical system.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, manifolds, taylor-expansion, dynamical-systems

Given this dynamical system: $$\begin{cases}x'=-4y+4y^3\\y'=-4x\end{cases}$$

I have seen that the system has a saddle at $(0,0)$. Now I am asked to approximate (using a third order Taylor expansion) the equation of the stable manifold near this point. I know that what I have to do is analogous to what the user @John B answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1613395/compute-local-equations-of-stable-unstable-manifolds). However my case is more complicated since I can't solve the system required to know the coefficients  $a,b,...$

If I take $\varphi(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+\cdots$ then I get the relations $$-4ba+4ba^3=0\\-4=-4b^2+12a^2b^2-8ca+8ca^3\\
0=-4bc+12a^2cb+12ab^3-8cb+24a^2b^2c-12da+12da^3
\\...$$

My problem is that every time I add a new relation a new coefficient appears, having always one more variable than equations in the system. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{cases}\frac{dx}{dt} =-4y+4y^3\\\frac{dy}{dt}=-4x\end{cases}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{y-y^3}$$
This ODE is separable and then integrable which leads to :
$$y(x)=\pm\sqrt{1\pm\sqrt{C-2x^2}}$$
Since in the wording of the question the point $(0,0)$ is mentioned as belonging to the solution, this condition implies $C=1$ and :
$$y(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-\sqrt{1-2x^2}}$$ 
Series expansion around $(0,0)$ :
$$y(x)=\pm\left(x+\frac14 x^3+\frac{7}{32}x^5+...\right)$$

Nevertheless, the above calculus is probably not the expected method.
$$ $$

OTHER METHOD : A series of the form $y(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+...$ is expected.

Preliminary inspection of $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{y-y^3}=\frac{x}{y}\:\frac{1}{(1-y^2)}$ makes understand that $y(x)$ is an odd function. Thus :
$$y(x)=a_1x+a_3x^3+...$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=a_1+3a_3x^2+...=\frac{x}{ (a_1x+a_3x^3+...)-(a_1x+a_3x^3+...)^3}$$
$$-x+(a_1+3a_3x^2+...)\big((a_1x+a_3x^3+...)-(a_1x+a_3x^3+...)^3 \big)=0$$
$$(a_1^2-1)x+(4a_1a_3-a_1^4)x^3+...=0$$
$$\begin{cases}
a_1^2-1=0 \quad\implies\quad a_1=\pm 1\\
4a_1a_3-a_1^4=0 \quad\implies\quad a_3=\frac{a_1^3}{4}
\end{cases}$$
$$y(x)=a_1\big(x+\frac14a_1^2 x^3+...\big)$$
$$y(x)=\pm\big(x+\frac14 x^3+...\big)$$

Comment: Why $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{y-y^3}=\frac{x}{y}\:\frac{1}{(1-y^2)}$ makes understand that $y(x)$ is an odd function? Also, since $x$ is a function, shouldn't it be $\frac{dy}{dx}=a_1+3a_3x^2x'+...$ (implicit differentiation)

Comment: Obviously if $x$ is changed  to $-x$ and $y$ is changed to $-y$ then $\frac{dy}{dx}$ remains the same and $\frac{x}{y}\frac{1}{(1-y^2)} $ remains the same. The equality continue to be valid. Thus if $(x,y)$ is solution also $(-x,-y)$ is solution. This proves that $y(x)$ is an odd function. Thus the series for $y(x)$ is made only with odd powers of $x$ : So, $a_0=a_2=a_4=…=0$.

Comment: The derivative of $a_3x^2$ with respect to $x$ (NOT with respect to $t$) is $3a_3x^2$ which is not $3a_3x^2\frac{dx}{dt}$ . Take care to not confuse the derivative with respect to one variable with the derivative with respect to another variable. The use of notation apostrophe is confusing in some cases.

Comment: What would you have done if the function was not odd or even?

Comment: If the function wax nor odd or even the series would be with all tems $y(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+...$ Same method but more boring calculus.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the same steps you did to solve this post with the function $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-sin(x)+0.5}{y}$. Using that this ode is separable and integrable I got $y(x)=\pm \sqrt{2(cos(x)-cos(x_0))+x-x_0}$ (the critical saddle point is $(x_0,0)$ but now I can't approximate this using the taylor expansion, maybe I should create a new post?

Comment: Let $x=x_0+t$ . Expand to series at $(0,0)$.